# SQL select results: multiple tables, custom fields

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I am attempting to get data from one table, whilst remove information that exists in another table.  However, I am also throwing a third table in the mix and have different column names and data from each table that I want to see in the output.

For example, I have this data:

---

Table 1: MEMBERS m

Columns: m.ID, m.cancelled_on

---

Table 2: MEMBER_CATEGORY mc

Columns: mc.ID, mc.activity, mc.activity_date

---

Table 3: MEMBER_CONTACT_SUPPRESSIONS mcs

Columns: mcs.ID, mcs.mailing_suppression, mcs.valid_to

---

I want to get all active members by filtering on m.cancelled_on IS NULL.

I then want to find from within these active members those that have participated in a particular activity within a certain date range.  For example, 'rowing' BETWEEN 1st December 2020 and 1st October 2021).

From that resultant set of data I would like to contact these people.  So I would then need to remove all of those people that have a certain mailing suppression (e.g. DO NOT CONTACT) that is valid to any date greater than yesterday.

RELATIONSHIP NOTE: m.ID = mc.ID = mcs.ID

Example data:

Table 1: MEMBERS m

| m.ID | m.cancelled_on |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | NULL |
| 2 | NULL |
| 3 | NULL |
| 4 | NULL |
| 5 | NULL |
| 6 | 2020-12-10 |

Table 2: MEMBER_CATEGORY mc

| mc.ID | mc.activity | mc.activity_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | rowing | 2020-12-20 |
| 1 | rowing | 2020-12-20 |
| 2 | rowing | 2021-08-20 |
| 3 | rowing | 2021-05-25 |
| 4 | rowing | 2019-12-20 |
| 5 | cycling | 2020-10-10 |
| 6 | rowing | 2020-12-10 |

Table 3: MEMBER_CONTACT_SUPPRESSIONS mcs

| mcs.ID | mcs.mailing_suppression | mcs.valid_to |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | NULL | NULL |
| 2 | DO NOT SMS | 2121-05-25 |
| 2 | DO NOT CONTACT | 2021-05-25 |
| 3 | DO NOT CONTACT | 2121-05-25 |
| 4 | NULL | NULL |
| 5 | DO NOT CONTACT | 2020-09-10 |
| 6 | NULL | NULL |

So the criteria I will apply, using the examples above:

```
m.cancelled_on IS NULL, AND
mc.activity = 'rowing', AND
mc.activity_date BETWEEN '2020-12-01' AND '2021-10-01'
```

Now remove the following from the resultant data:

```
mcs.mailing_suppression IN ('DO NOT CONTACT','DO NOT TELEPHONE','DO NOT EMAIL'), 
AND mcs.valid_to >= 2021-11-02)
```

I will then need the correct results to be displayed as follows:

| m.ID | m.cancelled_on | mc.activity | mc.activity_date | mcs.mailing_suppression | mcs.valid_to |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | NULL | rowing | 2020-12-20 | NULL | NULL |
| 2 | NULL | rowing | 2021-08-20 | DO NOT CONTACT | 2021-05-25 |

I've tried all sorts of JOIN, EXCEPT, INTERSECT combinations and I just can't seem to get it, so any help would be greatly appreciated right now!

Thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks @Michael for all of your help.

Answer (score 0):

Everything seems pretty straight forward so I'm guessing you are getting tripped up on how to exclude the DO NOT CONTACT members. You can use `NOT EXISTS` to accomplish this:

EDIT: Updated answer based on comments.

```
select distinct m.id, mc.activity, mc.activity_date
from members as m
inner join member_category as mc
on m.id = mc.id
inner join member_contact_suppressions as mcs
on m.id = mcs.id
where m.cancelled_on is null
and mc.activity = 'rowing'
and mc.activity_date between '2020-12-01' and '2021-10-01'
and not exists (
    select *
    from member_contact_suppressions as mcs1
    where mcs1.id = m.id
    and mcs1.mailing_suppression in ('DO NOT CONTACT', 'DO NOT TELEPHONE', 'DO NOT EMAIL') 
    and mcs1.valid_to >= '2021-11-02'
)
```

The `where mcs1.id = m.id` is the "link" between the subquery in `NOT EXISTS` and the outer query resultset. The `NOT EXISTS` part will exclude those members that meet the criteria in the subquery.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=962dfd98bb35f37d97c24491d6d634e6)

Comment: Thanks @Michael for all of your help.

Unfortunately, however, it is still not working.  This may be partly my fault in that I perhaps over-simplified that which is a much more complex database.

I have run your query and it presents me with 12603 rows.  If I run the data through using List Manager in our CARE NG CRM system, I get 5127 - which, I know, is the correct result.  The results from your query still come back with the mailing_suppression entries I wish to remove.

I think that the reason for this is that each client can have more than one member_contact_suppressions record.

Comment: Due to this it may be picking up all member_contact_suppressions records, including those I do not want.  My fault entirely for not mentioning this previously.

Would this therefore need a DISTINCT somewhere?  Thanks again!

Comment: My original query should filter out any members that have any DO NOT CONTACT records, but maybe I'm misunderstanding your requirements. Could you add some sample data that breaks the query so I can see what is going on?

Comment: Hi @Michael, I've just edited my post to include another entry in the suppressions table.  What is actually happening (to clarify my badly-worded previous comment!) is that the results contain all mailing_suppression records for that member.  I would like to de-dupe them so there is only one entry per m.contact_number - the rest appears to be exactly correct - thanks!!  (Result now seen is: 1, NULL, rowing, 2020-12-20, NULL, NULL / 2, NULL, rowing, 2021-08-20, DO NOT SMS, 2121-05-25 / 2, NULL, rowing, 2021-08-20, DO NOT CONTACT, 2021-05-25)

Comment: I guess I run into an issue wherein I am trying to push two records into one, but hopefully I can do this somehow..??  I actually don't care about displaying the suppressions so much and only kept it in to verify my results (and I'm happy your query, above, gets this done correctly).  What I really need to provide to the people contacting is m.ID and mc.activity_date, so the other fields can be stripped from display, if necessary.  So there should only be one entry for each individual m.ID.  I hope that makes sense!

Comment: I see. If you don't need the mailing_suppression and valid_to columns in the resultset then you can remove them and add a distinct to the select list. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Try it now. I removed cancelled_on, mailing_suppression, and valid_to and added distinct.

Comment: BOOM!  You are a star, mate.  I got 5441, which makes sense given there has been an extra day of data applied.  I'll confirm it in List Manager tomorrow as I am finished for the day now.  If all good, I'll mark your answer as the solution.  Thanks for everything!

Comment: Glad I could help!!

Comment: Okay..  This is annoying.  We've got every correct record, but I've now noticed an issue with data entered via an API from Salesforce!  What this means is that some of the activity records have been duplicated.  So, for example, there are two records for mc.ID 1.  Sorry to ask for yet another addition to this query, but is there any way at all that I can now strip the duplicates from here?  It would probably best be done on mc.activity_date.  Thanks again @Michael for al of your help - I'm so nearly there!

Comment: Can you add another record or two to the sample data so I can see what you mean? We'll get this working right!

Comment: thanks again for all your ongoing support.  It's been great!  I've added to the data and you can see another entry mimicking the duplicates created by the Salesforce API that I am getting in the member_category table.  Due to this I see two entries for mc.ID 1 in the results, even though there is only one corresponding mcs record.  If I could identify duplicates in the mc table on mc.activity_date and only display one, that would be the answer, I feel.  I can confirm there will be no false positives.  The duplicates will always be wrong.  Is it going to be yet another nested query..?

Comment: I added in the duplicate record to member_category and I don't have any duplicates in the results. Are you using the version of my answer with "distinct" in it?

Comment: I updated the db<>fiddle also so you can see what I'm working with.

Comment: I see your db<>fiddle and totally agree with the results.  I've just had a look again and can see that, in actual fact, the activity dates ARE different (sorry, I'm looking at a lot of data and am trying to do a million other unrelated jobs simultaneously!).  However, the difference is only a few days and doesn't correlate to what I see in the CARE interface.  I think the CARE GUI must be using a different table to present its data, but the duplicates are definitely there.  I'll keep looking into why, but thanks for all the help so far - I'll be back!!

Comment: A different date in the duplicated record you added last will create duplicates in the result. We can work around that if you only want one of the records, but we'll need to know which of the records you want to show in the results. Take a MAX(activity_date) maybe?

Comment: I hope you had a great weekend!  To come clean on the actual use of our data and suspend the ruse: it is actually for parents and their child's birth date.  So if there is a duplicate and the second record shows a couple of weeks after the first, this is VERY likely not to be two separate births.  Unless they are a Virginian opossum (I looked that up).  So we can safely say that if the activity_date (DoB) is so quickly after the first, we can keep the second record (I'm thinking the first record is an estimate and the second is an updated actual birth date).  Is this possible?

Comment: Okay, I have another field to throw into the mix that may help (or hinder!) - there is a mc.valid_from field that shows when the mc.activity was added.  If I could take the later of the two records based on this field (if the difference between activity_date 1 and activity_date 2 is less than 1 month) that should crack it, I think!  Am I makingthis more complicated than it need be....?

Comment: O dear.  I guess this one is now dead in the water then.  No complete solution, but we NEARLY got there.